# Unable to access EC2 instance after ip address change

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, putty, amazon-ec2

I inadvertently changed the IP address of my Amazon EC2 t2.micro instance.  As a result, I'm now unable to SSH back into the system.  I've rebooted it multiple times via the AWS Console, to no avail.  I've also updated the associated security group to accept all incoming traffic on all ports.  Still no luck.  Is there a way to check to see if the system is actually running?  I can't get any useful information out of the 'detailed monitoring' screen AWS provides...

Comment: I assume you are trying to ssh to the Public DNS or the Public IP that is listed for the instance? How did you change the IP address, exactly?

Comment: What specifically happens when you try to ssh into the host at its new address?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to SSH to the Public IP.  I changed the IP inadvertently when I was trying to assign an elastic IP to my VPC.  Even though I explicitly selected an elastic IP for VPCs rather than EC2s, when I tried assigning the IP it gave me the id of EC2 server.  My assigning the elastic IP to the EC2 instance the server's IP address changed.

I have since released the elastic IP and rebooted the system via AWS console multiple times.  Each of these operations has changed the IP address of my instance.

Comment: When I try to ssh into the host using PuTTY, it just sits there and then times out.  No response is received.

Comment: I can't seem to ping the new host from anywhere... including a different EC2 instance I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem stemmed from the fact that I had set up a Network access control list (ACL).  With it I had specified port 22 as an ingress (inbound) port but did not include port 22 as an outbound (egress) port.  Resetting my ACL inbound/outbound rules fixed the issue.

Here is the article describing various security levels on AWS:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html